# How to use RLMArray in Swift with Realm for Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift, realm

My app is mixed Objective-C and Swift, which forces me to use Realm for Objective-C. Now, I'm creating a new Realm model in Swift with an embedded `RLMArray`.

```
@objcMembers class KTPRestaurant: RLMObject {
    var name: String?
    dynamic public var tables: RLMArray<KTPTable>?
}
```

However, I keep getting an error saying that `'Property 'tables' is declared as 'id', which is not a supported RLMObject property type.`. How should I declare the `RLMArray`?

Comment: If you are using Realm Objective-C the `RLMObject` subclases should be written in Objective-C. Then include them in the bridge header and use them from Swift.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare your RLMArray properties with the following syntax:

```
@objc dynamic var tables = RLMArray< KTPTable >(objectClassName:KTPTable.className())
```

Please refer to this [RLMArray Properties](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#rlmarray-properties) from the Realm Docs.
If you have face this issues : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException'. Means You need to uninstall the app and reinstall the app to update the Realm.